# Apple Watch doesn’t show Race Route

Tags: watchos, apple-watch

I have an Apple Watch Series 8 with iOS 9.2 and I haven’t been able to get the Race Route feature to work.

I’ve run the same route several times using the Workout app. When I open the Activities app on the iPhone I can see the map and my route on previous runs. But when I select Outdoor Run on my watch and filter to Route, no routes show up.

I’ve restarted both the phone and the watch and made sure I’m at the start of my route before opening the Workout app.

Update: I suspected Apple may be sensitive to tiny variations in my route, particularly in the part that’s on a trail. So I tested yesterday by running the same 0.5 mile route on a sidewalk by a road known to Maps. It still wasn’t picked up.

Anything else I might be missing?

Comment: Is there a "record route" button to start registering a route?

Comment: No, should there be? From what I understand it’s automatic.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/creating_a_workout_route

Comment: That’s for developers who want to include the feature in their apps. I’m using the built in Workout app.

Comment: For what it's worth, my watch only shows one 'Route' from October 4th - despite the fact I've run the exact route a number of times since then ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

After updating my phone to iOS 9.2 the route now shows up. I thought I had already updated but the installation was stuck.